# Why doesn't LaTeX provided ACS style contain article titles

Tags: bibliographies

I have tried both:

```
\usepackage[style=chem-acs]{biblatex}
```

and

```
\bibliographystyle{achemso}
```

and nether one gives titles of articles. However the [ACS Style guide](http://library.williams.edu/citing/styles/acs.php) clearly specifies that this information should be there. Is this not the style that these packages are trying to provide or am I missing something else?

---

### Example

refs.bib:

```
@BOOK {KandR, AUTHOR  = "Kernighan, Brian W. and Ritchie, Dennis M.", TITLE   =
"{The C Programming Language Second Edition}", PUBLISHER = "Prentice-Hall,
Inc.", YEAR = 1988 } 
@ONLINE {CUEDCplusplus, AUTHOR  = "Love, T.P.", TITLE   =
"{CUED C++}", URL = "http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/languages/C++.html",
URLYEAR = 2010, PRESORT="aa" } 
@article{Akamatsu:2011dz, Abstract = {The
physicochemical properties of candidate compounds play important roles in the 
design of new pesticides. Pesticides must be absorbed by pests, be transported
to the target site, and then interact with proteins. Hydrophobicity is very
important for these processes. Log P, where P is the partition coefficient in
the 1-octanol/water system, is commonly used as a hydrophobic descriptor and 
correlates with membrane permeation and transport. It was recently reported
that permeability by the parallel artificial membrane permeation assay (PAMPA)
could be used to predict human oral absorption of passively transported
compounds. PAMPA, which is a rapid high-throughput screening system, may be
useful to predict pesticide absorption because PAMPA permeability can be
calculated using log P and other parameters. Electronic and structural
properties as well as hydrophobicity are important factors for protein-ligand
interaction. To show the importance of physicochemical properties, the classic
QSAR and CoMFA of neonicotinoids and prediction of bioavailability of
pesticides in terms of membrane permeability in comparison with drugs are 
described.},    Author = {Akamatsu, Miki}, Date-Added = {2012-07-06 13:37:41
+0200}, Date-Modified = {2012-07-06 13:37:41 +0200}, Doi = {10.1021/jf102525e},
Journal = {J Agric Food Chem}, Journal-Full = {Journal of agricultural and food
chemistry}, Mesh = {Anabasine; Animals; Biological Availability; Cell Membrane
Permeability; Drug Design; Humans; Imidazoles; Insecticides; Nitro Compounds;
Pesticides; Physicochemical Phenomena; Quantitative Structure-Activity
Relationship; Receptors, Nicotinic},    Month = {Apr}, Number = {7}, Pages =
{2909-17}, Pmid = {20879794}, Pst = {ppublish}, Title = {Importance of
physicochemical properties for the design of new pesticides}, Volume = {59},
Year = {2011}, Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/jf102525e}}
```

test.tex:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[style=chem-acs]{biblatex}
\defbibnote{books}{Only books!}
\bibliography{refs} 
\begin{document} 
foo\cite{Akamatsu:2011dz}
\printbibliography[prenote=books, type=book] 
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

[image: What is looks like]

Comment: It seems that there are contradictory guidelines, as [this sample article from the Journal of the American Chemical Society](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja210959p) shows no title for articles in the reference section.

Comment: The guidelines make it clear that this is optional: the guide  is not really that prescriptive, and most entries have at least a couple of variants. As @egreg says, the styles aim to reproduce what happens in ACS journals. They vary quite a bit, as each office sets its own policy. The default for both styles follows _Journal of the American Chemical Society_, which uses the standard chemistry approach of not giving titles.

Comment: Oh, you might want to compare my efforts with the [`chembst`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chembst) bundle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a package option (from the `achemso` documentation:)

> The `articletitle` option is a Boolean, and sets whether the title of a paper referenced appears in the bibliography. The default is `articletitle=false` for the `achemso` style and `articletitle=true` for the `biochem` style.

Similarly in `biblatex-chem`:

> The use of article titles varies between individual journals. The boolean option `articletitle` is available is control this behaviour. The standard settings for the `chem-acs`, `chem-angew` and `chem-rsc` styles have this option turned off, while the `chem-biochem` sets this option true.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=article]{achemso}
\setkeys{acs}{articletitle=true}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in first line:

```
\documentclass[journal=jcisd8,manuscript=article]{achemso}
```

`jcisd8` means journal of chem. info. and modeling.

Replace that with your journal code

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: You should _only_ use the the `achemso` class for submissions.

Comment: HI @JosephWright is there a way to keep another documentclass (like article), but having \bibliographystyle{achemso} which shows titles?

Comment: @bio Yes, you can load the _package_ and set the appropriate key